# Is there a simpler way to have an IObservable be asynchronously dependent upon another IObservable?

Tags: asynchronous, system.reactive

I'm new to RX, and I have my desired scenario working well, but it seems to me there must be a simpler or more elegant way to achieve this. What I have is an `IObservable<T>` and I want to subscribe to it in such a way that I end up with an `IObservable<U>,` by triggering an asynchronous operation that generates a U for each T it sees.

What I have so far (that works great, but seems cumbersome) uses an intermediate event stream and goes something like this:

```
public class Converter {
  public event EventHandler<UArgs> UDone;
  public IConnectableObservable<U> ToUs(IObservable<T> ts) {
    var us = Observable.FromEvent<UArgs>(this, "UDone").Select(e => e.EventArgs.U).Replay();
    ts.Subscribe(t => Observable.Start(() => OnUDone(new U(t))));
    return us;
  }
  private void OnUDone(U u) {
    var uDone = UDone;
    if (uDone != null) {
      uDone(this, u);
    }
  }
}

...

var c = new Converter();
IConnectableObservable<T> ts = ...;
var us = c.ToUs(ts);
us.Connect();

...
```

I'm sure I'm missing a much simpler way to do this...

Comment: Are you sure you want `Replay` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectMany` should do what you need, to flatten out the `IO<IO<T>>`

```
Observable.Range(1, 10)
        .Select(ii => Observable.Start(() => 
             string.Format("{0} {1}", ii, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)))
        .SelectMany(id=>id)
        .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I knew about SelectMany, but for some reason I hadn't considered this problem in terms of flattening out an observable of (single item) observables.

Comment: I noticed a problem with this, however - it blows up my process half-way through the event stream with OutOfMemoryException. My approach didn't do that...

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `SelectMany` is for:

```
IObservable<int> ts

IObservable<string> us = ts.SelectMany(t => StartAsync(t));

us.Subscribe(u => 
    Console.WriteLine("StartAsync completed with {0}", u));

...

private IObservable<string> StartAsync(int t)
{
    return Observable.Return(t.ToString())
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```

Keep in mind that if `StartAsync` has a variable completion time, you may receive the output values in a different order from the input values.